# Onclick Anchor not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 Rating Stars Radio Buttons, they are working fine, I also have a anchor tag and I need to check if any of the radio buttons has been checked before the redirection.

HTML

```
<-- index.html -->

<div class="stars-div">
    <div class="stars">
        <input class="star-input star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-5" for="star-5"></label>                                   
                            <input class="star-input star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-4" for="star-4"></label>
                            <input class="star-input star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-3" for="star-3"></label>
                            <input class="star-input star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-2" for="star-2"></label>
                            <input class="star-input star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-1" for="star-1"></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button-div">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-test" id="okB">
        <b>OK</b>
        &nbsp;
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now in my main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var okButton = document.getElementById('okB');
  $("#okB").on("click", isRated);
  function isRated () {
    var value = $("input[name=star]:checked").val();
    console.log('hola click')
  }
});
```

Ok, the problem is that every time I click the anchor nothing happen. What can I do to fish this ?

Comment: Where is your radio button? Please show enough of your code (see the "*[MCVE]*" guidelines for help) that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you wait with the execution of the JavaScript until the DOM has loaded? (e.g. `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`)?

Comment: Edited with more details

Comment: @JoseOsorio Edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide to use DOM or jQuery

Here is a link that does not reload the page - the code can be put into the head of the page

```js
$(function() {
  $("#okB").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // do not (re)load the page in the href
    var value = $("input[name=star]:checked").val();
    console.log('hola click',value)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-test" id="okB">
    <b>OK</b>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</a>
<div class="stars-div">
    <div class="stars">
        <input class="star-input star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-5" for="star-5"></label>                                   
                            <input class="star-input star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-4" for="star-4"></label>
                            <input class="star-input star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-3" for="star-3"></label>
                            <input class="star-input star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-2" for="star-2"></label>
                            <input class="star-input star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-1" for="star-1"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited with more details

Comment: but how can I make the anchor work if the value is not undefined ?

Answer (score 1):

It's surely because your `javascript` code is above the `HTML` in  your page.

So, when your browser reads your Js code, the link is not already in the DOM, so it can bind the event handler to the link.

Here's a working example, where the event handler is bound when `document` is ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#okB").on("click", isRated);
});


function isRated (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $("input[name=star]:checked").val();
    console.log('hola click')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-test" id="okB">
    <b>OK</b>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</a>
```

[EDIT]:

You have to prevent the default behavior of a link (e.g. changes the url of the page) by calling `preventDefault`on the `event`object (`e` in the snippet) passed to the `isRated` callback.

In addition, you can put a `#` in the href of the link or replacing you `a`tab by a `button` tag which is a better practice for Bootstrap buttons.

Comment: Edited with more details

Comment: Now it looks more and more like mine ;)